# My Hitachi external hdd is not detected

Tags: 11.10, mount, usb-drive

I tried it with window and the hdd is detected so I conclude this is not the hdd problem

Status when hdd usb is inserted

```
No@No-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5149:13d3  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 4971:1012 SimpleTech
```

status when usb is not inserted

```
No@No-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5149:13d3
```

Is there anyway to open my hdd throught ubuntu?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `uname -r`

Answer (score 2):

Run this command and reboot:

```
echo "blacklist uas" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

---

*This seems to be a [documented bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/868233).*